# Read and Write Structures in the Beckhoff Plc with Python Pyads Module(ADSError: symbol not found (1808))

Tags: python, linux, structure, plc

I am trying to read and write to structure variables in the CX9020 Benchoff Plc at Linux. I am doing the same thing as in the `Pyad`s documentation example but I am getting error. I added definitions and error to below . Thanks for your help.

PLC Definition Code :

```
TYPE sample_structure :
STRUCT
    rVar : LREAL;
    rVar2 : LREAL;
    rVar3 : LREAL;
    rVar4 : ARRAY [1..3] OF LREAL;
END_STRUCT
END_TYPE
```

[image: Twincat Screenshot]

Python Code :

```
import sys
import pyads

PLC_AMS_ID= '5.41.49.218.1.1'
SENDER_AMS = '192.168.0.5.1.1'
PLC_IP = '192.168.0.8'
PLC_USERNAME = 'Administrator'
PLC_PASSWORD = '1'
ROUTE_NAME = 'CX-682843'
HOSTNAME = '192.168.0.5'  # or IP
vel_f,vel_b,vel_l,vel_r =0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
sol_hiz,sag_hiz=0,0
vel_msg=0
pyads.set_local_address(SENDER_AMS)
pyads.add_route_to_plc(SENDER_AMS, HOSTNAME, PLC_IP, PLC_USERNAME, PLC_PASSWORD, route_name=ROUTE_NAME)
plc = pyads.Connection (PLC_AMS_ID, 851,PLC_IP)
plc.open ()

plc.write_by_name('GVL.sample_structure',[11.1, 22.2, 33.3, 44.4, 55.5, 66.6],pyads.PLCTYPE_LREAL * 6)
plc.read_by_name('GVL.sample_structure', pyads.PLCTYPE_LREAL * 6)
```

Error Message :

```
2022-07-26T08:43:12+0300 Info: Connected to 192.168.0.8
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sampleStruct.py", line 22, in <module>
    plc.write_by_name('GVL.sample_structure',[11.1, 22.2, 33.3, 44.4, 55.5, 66.6],pyads.PLCTYPE_LREAL * 6)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pyads/ads.py", line 900, in write_by_name
    self._port, self._adr, data_name, value, plc_datatype, handle=handle
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pyads/pyads_ex.py", line 1018, in adsSyncWriteByNameEx
    handle = adsGetHandle(port, address, data_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pyads/pyads_ex.py", line 777, in adsGetHandle
    PLCTYPE_STRING,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pyads/pyads_ex.py", line 638, in adsSyncReadWriteReqEx2
    raise ADSError(err_code)
pyads.pyads_ex.ADSError: ADSError: symbol not found (1808). 
2022-07-26T08:43:12+0300 Info: connection closed by remote
```

Answer (score 0):

You've created the structure , but you haven't done the implementation in GVL.

You have to add in GVL:

```
VAR_GLOBAL

    sample_structure : sample_structure;

END_VAR
```